# Why is my CAGradientLayer animating all changes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calayer, cagradientlayer

I have a `CAGradientLayer` that I want to scale as the user drags there finger. However, when I set the frame, the layer animates to the new size. This happens with other properties, too, including start/endPoint.

Here's an example:

```
_gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480-toHeight, 320, toHeight);
```

Yet, if I only call this when the user has dragged 10 or so pixels, the layer doesn't simply jump to the new size, it animates in a smooth but quick eased animation. I'm positive this isn't called in an animation block. To further debug, I also animate the frame of a `UIView` in the same scope and that doesn't animate.

I'm new to `CALayers`, so maybe I'm doing something way wrong.

Comment: have you wrapped up you code within.. `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];` and it's `commit`.. or you have forgot to `commit` after opening it? So as @mjisrawi says.. post some code..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of CALayer's properties are animated by default. You need to disable these implicit animations:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
// change layer's properties
_gradient.frame = newFrame;
[CATransaction commit];
```

[Here is a good sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GeekGameBoard/Introduction/Intro.html) to help you with learning Core Animation.

Answer (score 3):

From the Core Animation Programming Guide:

"Changing the value of an animatable layer property causes the layer to implicitly animate the change from the old value to the new value."

So if you don't want the animation, you need to tell iOS not to animate explicitly with:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.0];
_gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480-toHeight, 320, toHeight);
[CATransaction commit];
```

good luck!